# Struggling to pattern match using Perl/regex with this file name format: word1.word2

Tags: regex, perl

Im parsing some parameters in a Perl script and I'm struggling to match a parameter that has a file name format of "name1.name2". An example name might be "enroll.peacecorp"   My code looks like this:

```
my $parms = join(' ',@ARGV);
# other params here
$db_name  = $1  if ( $parms =~ /-dbname\s+(\w\.\w+)/ ); 
# more params here
```

But it does not seem to be working. I have tried setting the pattern to /-dbname\s+(\w.\w+)/ but no success there either. I also tried this one, which did work properly, but is not as flexible: /-dbname\s+(enroll.\w+)/

I know for some of you regex experts, this is not a tough problem. I'd appreciate some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: `\w` matches one single character so your best will be `n.name2`

Comment: Just add a `+` after the first `\w`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your regex from `(\w\.\w+)` to `(\w+\.\w+)`

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug in your regex (missing a `+`). You might consider using one of the [Getopt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) [modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), or even the built-in `-s` switch (see [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)) to parse your arguments. For an answer to your immediate problem, you can easily take the captured expressions from a regex like so:

```
my ($db_name) = $parms =~ /-dbname\s+(\w+\.\w+)/;
```

Alternatively, instead of joining `@ARGV` into a string and running a regex against it, just iterate through the list and take the argument after the `-dbname` argument:

```
my $db_name;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @ARGV; $i++) {
  if ($ARGV[$i] eq '-dbname') {
    $db_name = $ARGV[++$i];
  }
}

die "usage: $0 -dbname foo.bar\n"
  unless $db_name;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer to my immediate problem worked great.

Comment: @BentChainRing Happy to help! Please check the answer that was most helpful to you. :)

Comment: actually, each answer was helpful, informative, and confirming in its own way. can I check more then one?

Answer (score 0):

Just \w implies a single character.

You have to add parameters to that...

```
? = 0 or 1 of preceeding char.
* = 0 or MORE of preceding char.
+ = 1 or MORE of preceding char.

(?:([-]dbname)\s*)(\w+\.\w+)
```

Against the string "-dbname something.cool" it will return only "something.cool".

Adding Regex101 reference so you can see a break down of your regular expression.

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/pD8uC5/2)

**Update**

Noticed the intent for script arguments. My apologies. Regex updated. It will find the argument but it will only capture the name value... please let me know if you need the -dbname parameter as well or if just the name works for you. This regex is set to "match" but not include it.

Comment: If something is unclear to you just ask the OP for it, instead modifying the code based on your believes.